# How to add a custom route, controller, and action in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a Ruby on Rails and ActiveAdmin application. I didn't basically change any default configuration except adding and registering a few models.

I want to enable my application with a route like `GET /heartbeat` and respond with a simple string to client/user. I'm wondering how could I do the following steps:

1. Add a custom route to my `routes.rb` file.
2. Add a custom controller under `app/controllers` path.
3. Implement a custom action and respond to user directly without any view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

routes.rb:

```
get 'heartbeat' => "custom_controller#heartbeat"
```

custom_controller.rb:

```
class CustomController < ApplicationController
  def heartbeat
    render inline: "Some string to the client/user"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Avoiding the Rails render stack will save you some processing and be faster. You can do this at the router level via a simple Rack "application" that returns a response code:

```
get 'heartbeat', to: proc { [204, {}, []] }
```

Anything that responds to `call` and returns `[status, headers, body]` is rack compliant so you can leverage a proc to do just that, right in the router. In this case, we send a `204 No Content` which should be sufficient for a heartbeat, but you can always return custom data/headers.

**Update:**

I can only imagine that this  was downvoted because people don't understand why this is better. Here's a quick attempt to explain:

In case it wasn't clear, you don't need a controller action at all with this method. Here's the equivalent solution to the accepted answer:

```
get 'heartbeat', to: proc { [200, {}, ['Some string to the client/user']] }
```

Sticking that line in your Rails `routes.rb` file will be equivalent to creating a new controller, view and route entry, with one key difference: **It avoids the Rails response rendering stack** so should be much faster than the accepted solution.

Comment: Well, I think that's because you didn't provide a full answer given that the OP asked for a custom controller and action too

Comment: If you groked the answer, you'd realize that was because there's no need for a controller action since this renders at the Rack level and avoids the rail stack completely. The accepted answer may give the OP the solution he wanted, but this answer gives the OP what he needed. It does the same thing in a better way.